# Cannot find referenced source: package:web_ui/web_ui.dart

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have a project that uses Dart and the web_ui package. I just upgraded Dart to libv2, specifically:

```dart
Dart Editor version 0.3.1_r17594
Dart SDK version 0.3.1.3_r17594
```

I just updated web_ui to 0.3.0+2.

Now, I'm getting these errors:

```dart
Cannot find referenced source: package:web_ui/web_ui.dart
no such type "WebComponent"
"ChatWindowComponent" has no method named "dispatch"
```

When I run my build.dart, it completes successfully, but it doesn't create an out directory. Nor does it give any error messages.

What's going on? Why can't it find package:web_ui/web_ui.dart? I can clearly see that pub has set stuff up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue. See http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7822. The issue was closed today. I tried out a continuous build of Dart Editor, but that lead to different errors--I'll save that for another question.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run my build.dart, it completes successfully, but it doesn't create an out directory. Nor does it give any error messages.

I run the editor with 'automatically run pub' disabled. Creating a new web ui projects yields a few errors, after installing pub the errors are gone, but the timestamps of the files are to old now.

I changed the file that was to build and the out directory appeared immediately.